How to successfully find files in Android TotalCommander
I'm trying to find a database file downloaded by one of my apps, which is not in the app's folder in the /storage/emulated/0/Android/data hierarchy.  I know it's around 100 MB in size, so I'm asking TC to find look for anything which is greater than 90 MB.  But no matter what I do it doesn't find it.  It also doesn't find a file which I can see when I connect the phone to my Mac laptop, in Android File Transfer; this second file (whose name is "All The Houses", with no extension) is over 700 MB, so the search should find it.  It does find various app files, however, if I start the search sufficiently high up in the filesystem hierarchy.
I have tried setting the Search For field to each of the following in turn: * *.* All*   and the empty string.  In all cases I have turned the Size checkbox on and set it to search for > 90 M.  In all cases it fails to find either "All The Houses" or the file I actually want to find.
The manual, tutorial and online help are not useful; they don't contain any detail on what to do if the app doesn't find stuff.  I don't usually use TC, so I figure there must be something really simple that I'm doing wrong.
Would be grateful for pointers on what it is!
Running TC 3.42 on a Pixel 3 [and yes, I do know it's old, but it serves me]
